# Given a set of sets, find the magnitude (number of elements) of the smallest set containing at least one element from each set

Tags: runtime-analysis

I know that the hitting problem is NP hard, but is it possible to find the magnitude of the smallest set? Also, provide the runtime.

Comment: welcome to CS! What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

When we say that hitting set is NP-hard, we mean that the following decision problem is NP-hard: given a set system $S$ and an integer $k$, decide whether there is a hitting set for $S$ of size at most $k$.